# Is it appropriate to use a bounty to encourage voting for an idea proposed in an answer

Tags: discussion, bounty

In my question [How can I tell what is changing in Salesforce as they patch each pod?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/80546/102) Peter answered with a link to an existing idea. At the time of writing, there weren't many votes on it.

Is it appropriate to use a bounty for an existing answer to encourage voting on the idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see much harm in that. Though I'm not sure if that would really result in many extra votes for the idea.

As long as questions are not pure idea advertising but remain actual questions I would consider using bounties to attract attention within acceptable conduct :-)

Comment: So far +14 votes on the idea. :-)

Comment: If nothing else, this post drew my attention to it  :)   ....just voted it up.